# Table Com Input type File de Upload apenas uma linha escuta o evento

Tags: javascript

Olá, senhores eu tenho uma table aonde nela possui uma coluna que possui um input type file, ao pressionar o input apenas a primeira linha escuta o evento, vocês saberiam me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

```js
$("#uploadBtn").on('change', function(e) {
  
  });
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed" id="tblformacao">
<tr>

  <td> 
  <input id="uploadBtn" type="file" class="upload" onchange="UploadFile(this)" name="Anexar   Documento" />
  
  </td>
  
</tr>
```

Comment: acredito que seja devido ao fato de esta selecionado pelo `ID`, tente selecionar uma classe: `$(".upload").on('change', function(e) { ... })`, se for preciso, adicione uma classe adicional para esta finalidade.

Comment: @TobyMosque funcionou obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi a sua pergunta, acredito que o problema aconteça porque ID's devem ser utilizados somente uma vez dentro do documento.

Você pode selecionar os elementos input's dessa maneira:

```
$('input[type=file]')
```

Lembrando também que você pode definir quais são os arquivos aceitos pelo seu input type usando o atributo accept, dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]